# Remove values above threshold

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove values from a dataframe, which is temperature some values are 10.0, 10.5,40.0, but I have values which don't make sense like 140.0, 159.5.. which I wanna remove.
I use the following functions but I don't get any thing to be removed like the indices

```
def remove_outlier(df, col_name):
    threshold = 100.0  # Anything that occurs abovethan this will be removed.
    value_counts = df.stack().value_counts()  # Entire DataFrame
    to_remove = value_counts[value_counts >= threshold].index
    if(len(to_remove) > 0):
        df[col_name].replace(to_remove, np.nan)
    return df
```

Comment: Could you add some sample input and the expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

`df = df[df[col_name] < threshold]`

Or

`df = df[~ df[col_name] > threshold]`

Comment: After removing values from a data frame, don't forget to reset indices with `df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Still there are no values are removed,  you can find the dataset here, https://www.mediafire.com/file/m36ha4777d6epvd/median_data.xlsx/file
column S_temp_HOY

Comment: @andreahmed Did you include the `df = `?

Answer (score 1):

Extending [GRS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53045216/6775799)

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> d

  City  Temperature
0    A         10.0
1    B         10.5
2    C        140.0
3    D         30.0
4    E        145.0
5    F         99.0


>>> def remove_outlier(dataFrame, col_name='Temperature', threshold=100):
...     return dataFrame[dataFrame[col_name] < threshold]

>>> remove_outlier(d)

  City  Temperature
0    A         10.0
1    B         10.5
3    D         30.0
5    F         99.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`df.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) function of `pandas` with `@` operator to read the value of variable:

```
df = df.query('col_name < @threshold')
```